# Using Malayalam unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, python-unicode

The code:

```
import unicodedata
s=u'കക'
b=s.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
print(b)
```

produced correct output in Python 3.0 shell as **കക**.  But when i tried the same in Spyder(Python 2.7) (Set as default encoding scheme utf-8), it showed error as:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>
```

please provide a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The following code produces correct output in Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.6

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf_8 -*-
import unicodedata
s=u'കക'
b=s.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
print(b)
```

കക